# How to create an appRoleAssignment via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=cs) you should be able to create an appRoleAssignment via Microsoft Graph, however this doesn't work. In a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/issues/2) I was instructed to create the issue here. We have migrated most of our code from Azure Graph API to Microsoft Graph and this is the last piece that is missing.

Answer (score 3):

This finally worked for me!

There might be more optimized ways to post the JSON but I had to go to basics to make sure nothing is causing this to fail behind the scenes.

```cs
        const string ROLE_ASSIGNMENT_FORMATTER = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/{0}/appRoleAssignments";

        public static async Task AddApplicationUsers(string enterpriseAppId, string userId, string roleId)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = string.Format(ROLE_ASSIGNMENT_FORMATTER, enterpriseAppId);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", await GetAccessToken());

            var roleAssignment = new
            {
                appRoleId = roleId,
                principalId = userId,
                resourceId = enterpriseAppId
            };


            var content = new StringContent(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roleAssignment), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response  = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return ;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'd love to hear if you have any idea why the SDK did not work for you.  I have opened an issue here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/537 to track it.

Comment: @DarrelMiller I think I just couldn't find this method with the .NET MS Graph SDK. I checked pre-releases and I guess I was using the latest nuget version so eventually had to do it on my own based on the documentation and examples

Comment: Ahh, I see.  There is a different SDK for the beta API.  The links to the nuget packages are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-net-sdk

Comment: ha! this explains a lot, thank you! I had to write a lot of methods this way because I couldn't find them. I knew I should look more for the SDK but I thought the direct REST API is not too bad anyway :)